# SSDT not deploying CLR assembly when updating older database version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr

I'm trying to convert our roll your own database deployment code with SSDT. If I deploy the database as a fresh install the project's assembly is added to the Assembly list with no problems so that the CLR code runs fine. But if I am targeting an older version of the database before we used CLR then the assembly is not being deployed and the CLR calls fail.

I have looked at every publish option and database setting and I cannot determine why the SSDT is not adding the project's assembly when updating an older version of the database.

Comment: Have you compared the publish script between the two target DBs? What are the differences? Is "older version" of the DB the same version of SQL Server? Are you using the Data-tier Application properties (i.e. setting up a version number)? The publish process is incremental, so it checks the current state of the target DB when creating the publish script. You could also check the "Create script (.sql file)" option in Project Properties to see the full from-scratch install (not based on current DB state) to see what it is doing that might not be expected.